# Visualize PDF directly in an Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, adobe, activex

I am working on a project where one of the goals is to visualize directly PDF in an Excel Sheet.
At the moment, a function allows to consult the PDF by double-clicking on a wanted entry.

The code detect in which line the user is positionned and get the path to the document associated with this particular line. The path is called "DIRFAT".

My goal is, thanks to the ActiveX "Abode Acrobat Reader PDF" visualize directly the pdf in the sheet. The PDF will have to change each time the user change line.

My code is currently not working as nothing shows up in the Acrobat Reader window.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheets("DIVERS").Range("SELECTED_ROW") = Target.Row
Sheets("DIVERS").Range("SELECTED_COLUMN") = Target.Column

' Vérifie si la cellule sélectionnée est sur la feuille "FAT"
If Target.Worksheet.Name = "FAT" Then
    ' Récupère le chemin complet du fichier PDF à partir de la variable "DIRFAT"
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = DIRFAT
    Me.AcroPDF1.src = filePath

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Sorry but I haven't understand your message. Is my request possible or not ? If yes, whats wrong with my code ?